# Transiciones en Javascript, slideshow

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código de javascript para hacer un slideshow en mi página. Quiero agregarle transiciones, pero la verdad es que estoy recién empezando y no tengo muy claro como se podría hacer.
Mi codigo de Java script y HTML son los siguientes, y no tiene ninguna regla de CSS aplicada.

```
  var slideshows = document.querySelectorAll('[data-component="slideshow"]');
slideshows.forEach(initSlideShow);
function initSlideShow(slideshow) {

var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slideshow-example [role="list"] .slide'); 
var index = 0, time = 5000;
slides[index].classList.add('active');     
setInterval( () => {
  slides[index].classList.remove('active');
  index++;
  if (index === slides.length) index = 0; 

  slides[index].classList.add('active');

}, time);
```

}}

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="minibanner">
        <div class="banner-title">
            <div class="title1">your</div><div class="title2">music</div><div class="title3">here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-img">
            <div id="slideshow-example" data-component="slideshow">
                <div role="list">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="img/bieber.jpg" alt="justin bieber" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="img/shawnmendes2.jpg" alt="shawn mendes" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="img/harrystyles.jpg" alt="harry styles" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega también HTML y CSS para ver cómo funciona todo y poder sugerir algo.

Comment: ¿Y los estilos CSS?